# International student in USA with CPT part-time work authorization can work remotely for a UK company?

Tags: usa, working-visas, uk-visa, students

Can an international student studying in the USA with CPT part-time work authorization, work remotely for a firm in the UK? It is possible or one needs the UK work visa as well? If the UK firm offers fulltime remote work, can one take it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, F1 students can only work in certain situations:

- on-campus - foreign remote work is obviously not on-campus
- on OPT - in this case you would have an EAD, and can work for anyone full-time as long as it's in your field
- on CPT - for this you can only work for a specific company, and I don't think they would designate remote work for this
- if you get an EAD for economic hardship - in this case you can work for anyone full-time

I am assuming you don't have an EAD and this is not CPT, in which case, you can only work on-campus, so I would say the answer to your question is **no**, you cannot work remotely for this company while in F1 status in the US.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned it as CPT (part-time) work authorization. So even if CPT, remote work would not be designated for it? And the final option is called pre-OPT I believe. But I've been told in pre-OPT one could only work part-time?

Comment: Can a student request for full-time Pre-OPT if the student has only Thesis defense pending?

Comment: Edited the question with CPT now.

Comment: @RajeshThevar: For CPT I believe you applied to the school for CPT with an offer letter from a given employer, so if you did that with a local employer, I don't think you can change it to another employer. I am not sure whether a school will accept CPT for a foreign employer you are planning to do remote work for.